# Navigation using images nested inside Touchable Opacity

Tags: react-native, nested, react-navigation, touchableopacity

**Background:**

I've designed a custom footer for my app in React Native, I've set some images to act as icons. I'm trying to have them redirect to other pages of the app upon touch.

**What I have tried**

I've been trying to use the same images nested within TouchableOpacity components to have them redirect to other pages using react navigation.
This is my code:

```
export class Footer extends React.Component {
    
    render (){
        return (
            <View style = { styles.footStyle } >

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.push('Home')} >
                    <Image 
                        style = { styles.iconStyle }
                        source = {require('./img/home.png')}/>
               </TouchableOpacity>
               
               <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.push('Favoritos')} >
                    <Image 
                        style = { styles.iconStyle }
                        source = {require('./img/heart.png')}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.push('Search')} >
                    <Image 
                        style = { styles.iconStyle }
                        source = {require('./img/search.png')}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.push('Notifications')} >
                    <Image 
                        style = { styles.iconStyle }
                        source = {require('./img/bell.png')}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={ () => navigation.push('Help')} >
                    <Image 
                        style = { styles.iconStyle }
                        source = {require('./img/circle.png')}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
} 

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    footStyle: {
        paddingBottom: 0,
        paddingRight: 10,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        flex: 0.4,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        borderTopWidth: 1,
        borderTopColor: '#000000'
    },
    iconStyle: {
        flex: 0.2,
        height: undefined,
        width: undefined
    }
})
```

**Problem**

When I try and run the app in expo, the images are not rendering at all. I get my blank footer without any content. I've tried touching the footer to see if the images weren't rendering but the "button" actually worked, that didn't work.

**Question**

How exactly can I nest an image within a TouchableOpacity component? Is it even possible to use this method with React Navigation?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an Image component to work you should provide a height and width in style.

Here you are setting it as undefined
Try something like

```
 iconStyle: {
        flex: 0.2,
        height: 100,
        width: 100
    }
```

Also on the navigation, you will have to pass the navigation prop to the Footer. As its a class you should access it as `this.props.navigation.navigate()`

As your code for integrating the Footer is not here, its hard to comment on how to pass the prop to the footer.

Comment: I've assigned width and height as undefined so that the flex value is what shapes the image. Tried changing it to a set value but it's still not showing up. Guess the regards the navigation prop. Will try to rework that and if I get around it, I'm accepting this answer. Thanks.